# javascript and window open to file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I have been stuck for hours with this issue. Is there anyone willing to help me figure out what's wrong?

I've this script:

```
function open(command)
{
var filename; //filename
var ext = '.html'; //extension
filename=command.concat(number,ext); //string concatenation
window.open(filename,'_blank'); //open the file ie. help1.html
}

function number(){
 var html = document.getElementById("num").innerHTML; //get the number
 return html.toString();
}
```

and I'd like to make the html page open a file in a new window. Files are in this form:

help1.html

I'm getting the number from a paragraph in the html

```
<p id="num">1</p>
```

and via a button I'm calling the open function declared above:

```
<input type="button" value="Hint" onclick="open('hint')">
```

The only output I get is that it opens the same page but keeps loading through to infinite.

What am I missing? I'm running this script in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `open` as your function name.

Also, add parentheses to your function call:

```
filename=command.concat(number(),ext);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKervY